# How to get the URL of an asset pipeline image in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

How do you access the URL of an asset pipeline image in Rails (i.e., one in apps/assets/images)?

`image_tag('filename.jpg')` renders the image tags.

I thought that `image_url('filename.jpg')` should provide the url in the view?

However in production this is not rendering the hash or providing the correct CDN route.

`asset_url` also is not working.

Am I using the wrong helper? Or do I need to look for issues in my app's config?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see hash in URL because image doesn't exists. So, check that you have file on disk and file name passed as argument to `image_url` don't have mistakes.

Comment: the image is definitely present. It respond to `image_tag` and is displayed that way in other parts of the app (with the correct fingerprint hash and CDN path). I just cannot get URL only.